# No Details in Log: The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details

Tags: ant

I've created a very simple application (Just an index file), and a Java Servlet filter.

I'm seeing the following error in the logs on deploy from Netbeans:

```
Deployment is in progress...
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2Fuser%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext490289541373061276.xml&path=/EXD
http://localhost:8080/manager/deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2Fuser%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext490289541373061276.xml&path=/EXD
C:\Users\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EXDLogger\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1070: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 57 seconds)
```

There are not any errors in any of the other logs.

Any idea what is going on?

web.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>EXDLogger</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.cn.filters.EXDLogger</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>paramExclude</param-name>
            <!-- Parameters which should be excluded from the hash in determining
                 if a request is unique. Separate multiple values with a ; -->
            <param-value>PARAM_1;PARAM_2</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>EXDLogger</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Class being called:

```
package com.cn.filters;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class EXDLogger implements Filter {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        //Get the IP address of client machine.
        String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();

        //Log the IP address and current timestamp.
        System.out.println("IP "+ipAddress + ", Time "
                            + new Date().toString());

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {

        //Get init parameter
        String testParam = config.getInitParameter("paramExclude");

        //Print the init parameter
        System.out.println("Test Param: " + testParam);
    }
    public void destroy() {
        //add code to release any resource
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hacked an answer. I'm sure there are better ones. I updated the relevant section of my build-impl.xml as follows:

```
<target depends="init,-init-cos,compile,compile-jsps,-do-compile-single-jsp,-pre-dist,-do-tmp-dist-with-manifest,-do-tmp-dist-without-manifest,-pre-run-deploy,-pre-nbmodule-run-deploy,-run-deploy-nb,-init-deploy-ant,-deploy-ant,-run-deploy-am,-post-nbmodule-run-deploy,-post-run-deploy,-do-update-breakpoints" name="run-deploy"/>
<target if="netbeans.home" name="-run-deploy-nb">
    <!-- <delete dir="${deployTarget}"/> -->
    <copy toDir="${deployTarget}" overwrite="true">
        <fileset dir="${build.web.dir}"></fileset>
    </copy>
    <copy toDir="${deployTarget}/WEB-INF/classes" overwrite="true">
        <fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}"></fileset>
    </copy>
    <!-- <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="true" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/> -->
</target>
```

I then added to my project.properties:

```
deployTarget=c:/xampp/tomcat/webapps/EXD
client.url=http://localhost:8080/EXD/
```